# $\lim_{(x,y) \to (\frac{-k\pi}{2},\frac{k\pi}{2})} \frac{|\sin(x-y)|^a}{|x^2-y^2|}$ with $a>0, k \in \Bbb Z$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $a>0$, $k \in\Bbb Z$ and $k \neq 0$.

Evaluate: $\lim_{(x,y) \to (\frac{-k\pi}{2},\frac{k\pi}{2})} \frac{|\sin(x-y)|^a}{|x^2-y^2|}$

The solution indicated is $+\infty$, for every $a$, but I don't understand why.

For example, if $a=2$, moving on $(\frac{-k\pi}{2}+2t,\frac{k\pi}{2}+t)$, $t \to 0$, I obtain:

$$\frac{\sin(t)^2}{|3t^2-k\pi t|}\sim \frac{t^2}{k\pi |t|}\sim \frac{|t|}{k\pi} \to 0$$

Where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the limit exists? Because Wolfram says it doesn't. I'm not sure either.

Comment: You are not wrong. That limit does not exist for every $a$.

Comment: Why do you say it? Did you consider particular paths? Please write it as an answer, I'm interested too.

Comment: I have written my answer, let me know your thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let $a>0$, $\;k\in\Bbb Z$ and $\;k\neq 0\;.\;$
> Evaluate: $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to\left(-\frac{k\pi}{2},\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)}\dfrac{|\sin(x-y)|^a}{|x^2-y^2|}$

It results that

$\begin{align}
\dfrac{|\sin(x-y)|^a}{|x^2-y^2|}&=\dfrac{|\sin(x-y+k\pi)|^a}{|x-y+k\pi|^a}\cdot\dfrac1{|x-y|}\cdot\\
&\cdot\dfrac{|x-y+k\pi|^a}{|x+y|}\;\;,
\end{align}$

for any $\;(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\land y\ne\pm x\land y\ne x+k\pi\;.$

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to\left(-\frac{k\pi}{2},\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)}\dfrac{|\sin(x-y+k\pi)|^a}{|x-y+k\pi|^a}=\lim\limits_{t\to0}\dfrac{|\sin t|^a}{|t|^a}=1\;,$

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to\left(-\frac{k\pi}{2},\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)}\dfrac1{|x-y|}=\dfrac1{|k|\pi}\;,$

but

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to\left(-\frac{k\pi}{2},\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)}\dfrac{|x-y+k\pi|^a}{|x+y|}\;$ does not exist, indeed,

by letting $\;X=x-y+k\pi\;$ and $\;Y=x+y\;,\;$ we get that

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to\left(-\frac{k\pi}{2},\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)}\dfrac{|x-y+k\pi|^a}{|x+y|}=\lim\limits_{(X,Y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{|X|^a}{|Y|}\;.$

If $\;\lim\limits_{(X,Y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{|X|^a}{|Y|}\;$ existed, then the value of the limit would be the same on every subset $\;S\;$ of the domain of the function $\;\dfrac{|X|^a}{|Y|}\;$ for which $\;(0,0)\;$ is a limit point of $\;S\;,\;$ but

$\;\lim\limits_{(X,Y)\to(0,0)\\Y=m|X|^a}\dfrac{|X|^a}{|Y|}=\dfrac1{|m|}\;$

is not the same in fact it depends on $\;m\;,\;$ hence

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to\left(-\frac{k\pi}{2},\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)}\dfrac{|x-y+k\pi|^a}{|x+y|}=\lim\limits_{(X,Y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{|X|^a}{|Y|}\;$

does not exist, consequently

even $\;\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to\left(-\frac{k\pi}{2},\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)}\dfrac{|\sin(x-y)|^a}{|x^2-y^2|}\;$ does not exist.